# Is it possible to override a Jest .skip() from the command line?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have an integration test that requires a small amount of API credits from a third party. The tests are normally `.skip`ped, but occasionally I wish to run them and spend the credits.

Right now I manually remove the `.skip`, run:

```
npx jest -t 'integration tests'
```

...then re-add the `.skip`. However I'm concerned that I'll accidentally commit the removed `.skip`, and telling colleagues to remove the `.skip` before they run the tests is a hassle.

Is it possible to override a Jest `.skip` from the command line? The [Jest docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/cli) don't mention such a thing but there may be some other way.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Based on @jonrsharpe's excellent answer, but making the code intention more explicit, as `_it`, `xit`, and `it` at the same time is difficult to read:

```js
const testOrSkip = process.env.RUN_SKIPPED_TESTS ? test : test.skip;

testOrSkip("behaves correctly", () => {
  expect(true).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Testing it:

```
$ npx jest src/backend/runme.test.ts

Test Suites: 1 skipped, 0 of 1 total
Tests:       1 skipped, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.566 s
Ran all test suites matching /src\/backend\/runme.test.ts/i.

$ export RUN_SKIPPED_TESTS='true'

$ npx jest src/backend/runme.test.ts

 PASS  src/backend/runme.test.ts
  ✓ behaves correctly (3 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.951 s
Ran all test suites matching /src\/backend\/runme.test.ts/i.
```

Answer (score 2):

Per [the documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/cli) the Jest CLI has no such option. However it would be straightforward enough to do something like:

```js
const _it = process.env.RUN_ALL ? it : xit;

_it("behaves correctly", () => { /* ... */ });
```

to allow you to control whether certain tests are skipped or run using an environment variable.

Alternatively you could use the various test discovery options in the [configuration](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration/) to group your tests by e.g. filename convention and provide entrypoints for running different groups as needed. For example, using [projects](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration/#projects-arraystring--projectconfig) with different `testMatch`es, you could do something like:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest --selectProjects some",
    "test:all": "jest",
    "test:other": "jest --selectProjects other"
  }
}
```

Comment: I suspected as much re: the option not existing. What is `xit`?

Comment: @mikemaccana [_"Also under the aliases: `it.skip(name, fn)`, **`xit(name, fn)`**, and `xtest(name, fn)`"_](https://jestjs.io/docs/api#testskipname-fn)